# Which class should we use for sending sms/text messages?

Tags: android

What class can we use to send a text message? I tried this on the emulator, 2.0:

```
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(...);
```

and that works ok. On my G1 running 1.5, I get a verify error, guessing because SmsManager is not available in 1.5. Maybe for 1.5 we need to use the deprecated class?:

```
android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager
```

is that correct, or is there some other class we're supposed to use for sending text messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. android.telephony.SmsManager is only available for API level 4 and up (a.k.a Android 1.6). [See the docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html). You can use [Android.os.Build.Version](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT) to figure out which to use on a given platform.